# Viewing YouTube video inside app with return to previous ViewControlloer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, youtube, ios6

I'm trying to integrate in my app a youtube video. But I want it to resume to the calling viewController when video finished. I've succeeded to almost implement that but in my way the user must press done button and then another to get back to the original ViewController.

This is the code I use, Please help, I prefer with ref to full code or code example.

YouTubeView.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YouTubeView : UIWebView
{
}

- (YouTubeView *)initWithStringAsURL:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame mimeSubType:(NSString *)mimeType;
@end
```

YouTubeView.m :

```
#import "YouTubeView.h"

@interface YouTubeView ()

@end

@implementation YouTubeView


- (YouTubeView *)initWithStringAsURL:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame mimeSubType:(NSString *)mimeType
{
NSString *strMimeType;

if([mimeType length]>0)
{
    strMimeType = mimeType;
}

else
{
    strMimeType =@"x-shockwave-flash"; //@"x-shockwave-mp4";
}

if (self = [super init])
{
    // Create webview with requested frame size
    self = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    // HTML to embed YouTube video

    NSString *videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                 <html>\
                 <head>\
                 <style type=\"text/css\">\
                 iframe {position:absolute; top:50%%; margin-top:-130px;}\
                 body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
                 </style>\
                 </head>\
                 <body>\
                 <iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"240px\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
                 </body>\
                 </html>", urlString];

    [self loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];

}

return self;

}


- (void)dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And a button that points to *on main ViewController :
    -(IBAction)runTestVideo:(id)sender {

```
NSString *strNormalVdoURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/TgLqH9n57B0"];

YouTubeView *videoVw = [[YouTubeView alloc] initWithStringAsURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strNormalVdoURL] frame:CGRectMake(0,0,315,420) mimeSubType:@"x-shockwave-flash"];

                        [self.view addSubview:videoVw];
                        [videoVw release];
                        videoVw = nil;

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if my method would work on yours as for mine, I had the view hidden when the video is playing. After the user pressed the done button, the movie controller will exit and the view is shown.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector (MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullScreen;) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name: MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];

[movieController stop];
[movieController.view removeFromSuperview];

view.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: Could you do something such that the user doesn't have to press the done button? Meaning when movie finish it would be like done button.